# NUSOAP problem using free web hosting sites

Tags: php, service, nusoap

I've been trying to figure out what's wrong and what is the problem with this following PHP code, which is trying to make a SOAP call. I can't get it to work when I host the PHP on free web hosting sites

```
include_once("nusoap/lib/nusoap.php");

// create the client and define the URL endpoint 
$client = new nusoap_client('http://xxxyyy.zzz:1881/');

// set the character encoding, utf-8 is the standard. 
$client->soap_defencoding = 'UTF-8'; 

$client->call('sendSMS', array( 'uName' => 'kd81fg',
          'uPin' => '18416',
          'MSISDN' => '09156300965',
          'messageString' => 'THIS IS A SAMPLE MESSAGE',
          'Display' => '1',
          'udh' => '',
          'mwi' => '',
          'coding' => '0' ),
          "http://ESCPlatform/xsd");
```

When I tried using this hosted on my localhost, it work, but when I try to upload it (I tried so many free web hosting sites) to a web hosting site, and try to run it, it will not work.

I don't know what's wrong but I'm pretty sure that the code is perfect. I'm guessing that the free web hosting sites that I tried do not allow SOAP / XML , or maybe cURL is disabled, or url_fopen is Off on their php.ini (config) or something . I don't really know what's wrong right now and I need to finish what I'm doing right away.

UPDATE: I tried to echo what's the error and here what it says

> HTTP Error: Couldn't open socket
>   connection to server http://xxxyyy.zzz:1881/, Error (111) Connection refused.

I checked the phpinfo for curl and stuff.

I was thinking of that too that maybe the problem is on the free hosts that they dont allow connection on port 1881, but I tried to scan and check if 1881 is open on my localhost, and it says my 1881 is closed, and now I'm confused.

Answer (score 1):

Probadly port 1881 is closed on the free hosts. Try to close it on your pc/router. If the same error appears than this should be the problem.

EDIT: Did you check the phpinfo() for curl and stuff?

EDIT 2: Don't you have to add the client's host to your profile at the service provider's site like when you want to use the Google maps API?

Answer (score 0):

Very often free web hosts will block *outgoing* ports. If you can set up a reverse proxy with apache or nginx (I'm assuming you're hosting the SOAP server).